# How to get week start date Sunday and week end date Saturday in php

Tags: php, date

How to get week start date Sunday and week end date Saturday in php.

I try my self below to code am getting Week Start Date as Monday Week End Date as Sunday.

```
$cdate = date("Y-m-d");
$week =  date('W', strtotime($cdate));
$year =  date('Y', strtotime($cdate));      
$firstdayofweek = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}+1"));
$lastdayofweek = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}-7"));
```

Thanks,
Vasanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `DateTime`, which is a little bit nicer to work with than `date` and `strtotime` :) :

```
$today = new \DateTime();
$currentWeekDay = $today->format('w'); // Weekday as a number (0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday)

$firstdayofweek = clone $today;
$lastdayofweek  = clone $today;

if ($currentWeekDay !== '0') {
    $firstdayofweek->modify('last sunday');
}

if ($currentWeekDay !== '6') {
    $lastdayofweek->modify('next saturday');
}

echo $firstdayofweek->format('Y-m-d').PHP_EOL;
echo $lastdayofweek->format('Y-m-d').PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your local configuration :

```
setlocale('LC_TIME', 'fr_FR.utf8');
```

Change 'fr_FR.utf8' by your local.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code like below. This code is correct ? but it's worked for me.

```
$cdate = date("Y-m-d");
$week =  date('W', strtotime($cdate));
$year =  date('Y', strtotime($cdate));      
echo "<br>".$firstdayofweek = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}-0"));
echo "<br>".$lastdayofweek = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}-6"));
```

Comment: If it works for you and your are satisfied with your solution: go for it!