# Week Number when week starts on saturday

Tags: php, algorithm, date

How do you find the week number based on Saturday as the week starting day (Saturday -> Friday)? I've been having an inordinate amount of trouble figuring this one out. A PHPsolution would be appreciated, but any example in any language would do as well.

My companies work week is from saturday (Day 1) to friday (Day 7), I need to be able to display the week number (as in week 23 of 52/53). I might be confused and the week number given by the normal `Date('W', $time)` function is sufficient, but I doubt it.

I've found possible solutions in Excel, but I haven't done VBA for a really long time, and can't make heads nor tails of [this implementation](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/442762-week-number-saturday-friday-working-week.html).

Comment: Week number based on what? Since the start of the year? Is http://stackoverflow.com/q/4896452/56778 of any use to you? How about the other related questions shown on this page (below and to the right)? Or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/30056515/56778 would be useful. You need to do a little research.

Comment: How do you define "week number"?  Is it since some date or do you mean  the number within the week (Saturday = 1, Sunday = 2, etc.)?

Comment: Please expand the question with exactly what you need. I.e. with sample inputs and expected outputs especially for dates around the beginning/end of a year. If you have a working implementation based on a different start date for the week, faking it by offsetting the day should be possible, I think.

Comment: I'm having trouble doing the math in my head and so have little examples to give

Comment: I'm going to go ahead an downvote this low-quality question.  It is very, very difficult to understand the question (as is your answer -- surely there's a better way). You have posted no coding attempt in the question, no sample input/output, and thus will be of no use to future readers.  If you can improve this question to make it clear, ping me and I'll consider retracting my downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These functions seem to solve my problem, though testing of more distant years might be necessary:

```
// The N option gives the normal week day, arithmetic makes it return my custom week days
function getDayOfWeek(\DateTimeImmutable $date)
{
    return ($date->format('N') + 2) % 7;
}

function getWeekNumber(\DatetimeImmutable $date)
{
    // Recursive function that loops through every day until it gets the start of a week
    $startOfWeek = function (\DateTimeImmutable $date) use (&$startOfWeek) {
        return (getDaysOfWeek($date) === 1)
            ? $date : $startOfWeek($date->modify('+1 day'));
    };

    // The z option tells us what day of the year this is, 
    // not a 100% sure this step is necessary
    if (getDayOfWeek($date === 1) {
        $nbDays = $date->format('z');
    else {
        $nbDays = $startOfWeek($date->modify('-7 days'))->format('z');
    }

    // Divides by the number of days in a week to get the number of weeks
    return ceil($nbDays / 7);
}
```